# Android java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call while result is not pending

Tags: android

I have a logout funcion. So when user logs out I want to abort BroadcastReceiver. But getting error as in Title. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void logout(Context context, String empid)
{
    try
    {
        Log.d("Testing", "TRY 2  LOGOUT me " + empid );
        try
        {
            Log.d("Testing", "TRY handle logout");
            db = new DbAdapter_User(context);
            db.open();
            db.handleLogout();
            db.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Testing", "CATCH handlelogout " + e.toString());
        }
        Log.d("Testing", "When logout class is " +  context.getClass());
        if (!context.getClass().equals(LogIn.class))
        {
             Log.d("Testing", "In IF When logout class is " +  context.getClass());
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LogIn.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        }
        Log.d("Testing", "logout: setting Global variables ");
        ((GlobalMobileVianet)context.getApplicationContext()).setUserId("000000");
        ((GlobalMobileVianet)context.getApplicationContext()).setPassword("");
        Log.d("Testing", "logout: DONE setting Global variables ");
        try
        {
            Log.d("Testing", "TRY session manager aborted");
            SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager();
            sessionManager.abortBroadcast();
         }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Testing", "CATCH session manager aborted " + e.toString());
        }
         LogoutNotification(context);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Testing", "CATCH 2  LOGOUT me " + e.toString() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat. What line causes the error?

Comment: Post a complete stack trace.

Comment: Also, when you log an exception, you should use [`Log.d(String, String, Throwable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)) version so that the full stack trace is logged.

Comment: Ok. I added e.getStalkTrace() in Log. Got "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call while result is not pending [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4136f798"

Comment: It's getting catched in "CATCH session manager aborted "